# Viewing and copying document on a laptop onto a usb only using command prompt

Tags: cmd, copy, usb, command-prompt

I am trying to download a file onto a usb from my laptop which is suffering from software issues. I used the command C:users\username>\dir documents on another pc, and was able to view the documents in the folder however, on the laptop in question, the command did not work and I was given the message "The system cannot find the path specified." I am trying to find the name of the document I need to copy so I am requesting a command which enables me to view all documents in the folder. After I find the name of the document, I am also unaware of how I can use command prompt to copy the file onto the USB i have inserted. 
I am accessing the command prompt through System Recovery. I do not know code in any form. IMPORTANT Information which may be the reason for the lack of ability to do anything. When I type prompt>dir ****.docx /s /p, I get the message Volume in drive C has no label rather than Windows 7.

Comment: The System Recovery Console does not have the full functionality of `cmd`. Only a few essential commands are available.

Answer (score 1):

This could help-
http://www.dummies.com/computers/operating-systems/windows-xp-vista/how-to-search-for-files-from-the-dos-command-prompt/

As for copying files in cmd, it's as easy as-

```
prompt>copy <source> <destination>
```

For changing the drive (to the USB drive), use the "/d" option-

```
prompt>cd /d <USB drive name>
```

To view all the contents of current directory, use "dir"-

```
prompt>dir
```

Comment: 1. the copy command is resulting in the message "< was unexpected at this time."

Comment: You are not supposed to include the angle brackets; just the path/file name

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you're not using right syntax. Kindly make cd c:\users and than write dir like this `C:> cd C:/Users` than your directory will be changed after that you can see C:/Users. So you can write dir in order to see your directories

Comment: 2 things, 1. I deleted the section /username>/ from the question which i will add right after this, 2. "Access is denied." If this was not clear, I am accessing the command prompt using the System Recovery Options.